# How to change different language to different font-size at same line without unique each container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to change different language to different font-size at same line without unique each container? is it possible? with css or javascript?

```
div{
    font-family: "English", "中文" 
    font-size: 20px;
    // I need to make "中文" font-size 10px.
}



<div>This is English. 這是中文 This is English</div>
<div>This is English. 這是中文這是中文這是中文 This is English</div>
...
```

Comment: It's not possible. CSS can only target whole element nodes (apart from some pseudo elements, such as `::first-letter`).

Comment: You will need a separate container if you want to change the `font-size` only for 中文.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for reply,   the browser can detect text is which language choose which font-family?, wondering how to do it?

Comment: Afaik, no, the browser cannot detect which language a certain text is in.

Comment: can js detect text language??

Comment: JavaScript can detect characters by Unicode-based regular expressions which is often the same thing as language. Sometimes though, the same characters in Unicode are reused across different languages (like Chinese, Japanese, and Korean). HTML like `lang="zh"` is meant to differentiate by language too (though if we don't know in advance what language is meant by a character, we can't add appropriate mark-up). My answer was based on an assumption that the characters were Chinese and not meant to be part of Japanese or Korean.

Comment: FYI, the HTML usage of `lang="zh"`, etc. may cause a slight font appearance change in some cases since there are somewhat different conventions across language for styling certain characters.

Comment: @BrettZamir I need detect Traditional Chinese

Comment: While you can detect characters which are traditional Chinese only, some characters are shared by traditional and simplified so you will not be able to distinguish them unless you know in advance what the characters will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you alter the text using JavaScript (since your question allowed for JavaScript), you can use CSS upon the results changed by JavaScript (which as others have said, requires adding a container).

For example :

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Note that the following might also be used for Japanese or Korean
    // Note also that I have not included (deprecated) compatibility characters. As 
    //   per http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/#BlockListing , to cover those
    //   you would need to add:
    //     1. \u3358-\u3370\u337B-\u337F\u33E0-\u33FE (e.g., immediately after "\u32CB")
    //     2. \uFA2E-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9 (e.g., immediately after "\uFA29")
    //     3. Replace \uFA0E\uFA0F\uFA11\uFA13\uFA14\uFA1F\uFA21\uFA23\uFA24\uFA27-\uFA29 with \uF900-\uFA2D OR if you want to keep the compat. listed separately from non-compat. (though there is no need for this), add the following, e.g., before \uFA0E: \uF900-\uFA0D\uFA10\uFA12\uFA15-\uFA1E\uFA20\uFA22\uFA25\uFA26\uFA2A-\uFA2D
    //     4. Immediately before ")+\s?)+/g", add |\ud87e[\udc00-\ude1d]

    // The portion \u2E80 up to \u32CB is for punctuation and special characters like radicals,
    //  but this does not support some punctuation characters which might be reused outside of 
    //  CJK as well as in CJK.
    var chineseChars = /((?:[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u2FF0\u2FFB\u3000-\u303F\u3105-\u312D\u3190-\u31B7\u31C0-\u31E3\u3220-\u3243\u3280-\u32B0\u32C0-\u32CB\u4E00-\u9FCC\u3400-\u4DB5\uFA0E\uFA0F\uFA11\uFA13\uFA14\uFA1F\uFA21\uFA23\uFA24\uFA27-\uFA29]|[\ud840-\ud868][\udc00-\udfff]|\ud869[\udc00-\uded6\udf00-\udfff]|[\ud86a-\ud86c][\udc00-\udfff]|\ud86d[\udc00-\udf34\udf40-\udfff]|\ud86e[\udc00-\udc1d])+\s?)+/g;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
        chineseChars,
        '<span lang="zh">$1</span>'
    );
};
```

with your CSS:

```
body {font-size: 12px;} 
span:lang(zh) {font-size: 10px}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Re6NH/8/)

My use of `lang="zh"` is based on an assumption that you know these to be used for Chinese as opposed to Japanese or Korean. If you do not know, you can change the span in JS to this:

```
'<span class="cjk">$1</span>'
```

and the Chinese part of the CSS to this:

```
span.cjk {font-size: 10px}
```

That won't make any assumptions about the language, only the characters.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6UX9/10/)

Comment: thanks for reply. what is `\u4E00–\u9FCC\u3400–\u4DB5\uFA0E\…`?  can you explain in detail after `replace(..`  thanks

Comment: the unicode representation of the Chinese characters.

Comment: Updated now after actual testing :)  I'm looking, as sevenseacat said, for the Chinese characters as identified by a Unicode-based regular expression, and then taking the result and grouping it within a Chinese language span tag which gets targeted by my preexisting CSS.

Comment: My regular expression is long because it tries to be exact in finding every possible Chinese character (and of course there are many, esp. if including ancient ones) and nothing more.

Comment: It doesn't appear to find `怎么做` when I add it in to your jsFiddle.

Comment: @BrettZamir  if is an article include a lot of text, this will increase too much tags.. any better idea?

Comment: @user1775888 : No other ideas; there is no targeting of characters without markup.

Comment: @setek: It's working; see http://jsfiddle.net/39Bup/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/CM364/1/ (I made the font size difference more noticeable)

Comment: @BrettZamir Hmm I thought perhaps it's if you put English then Chinese then English then Chinese, but the first line does that and works. But this doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/CM364/2/ (All I did was add more text to the end.)

Comment: @setek: Yeah sorry, I had a slight bug in that I was requiring whitespace at the end; now fixed at http://jsfiddle.net/39Bup/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/CM364/5/ and above.

Comment: @user177588 : also bear in mind that the above code is finding blocks of connected text, not adding tags for each individual character.

Comment: Thanks! this seems the best solution.

Comment: I'm wondering did you use this method before for your project??  if it is in a blog system, not too weird?  like make server loading too heavy or something?      just tried to make graphic designer content.

Comment: If it is used in client-side JavaScript it won't affect the server load at all because the changes will be taking place in the user's browser. Thus there is no extra code to deliver (besides the few lines of JS and CSS) unless you were trying to send back the text with the span tags (which there probably should be no need to do since you can always reapply the client-side JS as needed).

Comment: And the designer won't have to do anything different besides allow for the CSS rules and JS I mentioned (and even the CSS you could adapt to change into JS if you preferred, but usually better to let the designer have the ability to control all styling).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/qozidepi/1/watch?js,output

JS:

```
// Get the div
var div = document.getElementById("text");

// Get the value
var value = div.innerHTML;

// Regular expression finds Chinese characters and wraps them
// in a span tag, which have font-size 40px
value = value.replace(/([\u3400-\u9FBF]+)/g, function(match){
  return "<span>" + match + "</span>";
});

// Set the div's value
div.innerHTML = value;
```

Comment: Are you able to also pull in the punctuation into the `span`? So including `？。，（）【】` etc.

Comment: user3244808's code may cover a lot of characters, but is not as comprehensive as in my answer, though my answer also does not include punctuation. To include that, see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/#BlockListing for the other code point ranges necessary.

Comment: Actually, I think the code here is a little too aggressive in including a few characters which are not or may not be Chinese (though admittedly if it is only a comparison between English and Chinese, it should not matter).

Comment: @BrettZamir and @ setek, yep, both of you are right. After having posted the answer did I realize that mine is a bit limited in not including punctuation.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include CJK-specific punctuation, but it doesn't include those which might be reused for other purposes in other languages (such as a few of those given by @setek). I also added notes about how to add support for finding compatibility characters (characters which users might post but which are deprecated as far as Unicode is concerned).

Comment: @BrettZamir fantastic, thanks! I've found this site: http://unicode-table.com/en/sections/cjk-symbols-and-punctuation/ easier to find the characters I want to include, just mentioning for reference.