# Adding a class to all English text in HTML?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

The requirement is to add an englishText class around all english words on a page. The problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981619/how-to-change-different-language-to-different-font-size-at-same-line-without-uni/21982034), but the Javascript solutions wont work for me. I require a PHP example to solve this problem. For example, if you have this:

```
<p>Hello, 你好</p>
<div>It is me, 你好</div>
<strong>你好, how are you</strong>
```

Afterwards I need to end with:

```
<p><span class="englishText">Hello</span>, 你好</p>
<div><span class="englishText">It is me</span>, 你好</div>
<strong>你好, <span class="englishText">how are you</span></strong>
```

There are more complicated cases, such as:

```
<strong>你好, TEXT?</strong>
<div>It is me, 你好</div>
```

This should become:

```
<strong>你好, <span class="englishText">TEXT?</span></strong>
<div><span class="englishText">It is me</span>, 你好</div>
```

But I think I can sort out these edge cases once I know how actually iterate over the document correctly.

I can't use [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981619/how-to-change-different-language-to-different-font-size-at-same-line-without-uni/21982034) to solve this because:

1. This needs to work on browsers that don't support javascript
2. I would prefer to have the classes in place on page load so there isn't any delay in rendering the text in the correct font.

I figured the best way to iterate over the document would be using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

But the problem is that if I try this:

```
foreach ($html->find('div') as $element)
{
    // make changes here
}
```

My concern is that the following case will cause chaos:

```
<div>
       Hello , 你好
       <div>Hello, 你好</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's going to go into the first div and then if I process that node, I will be processing the node within that too.

Any ideas how to get around this and only select the nodes for processing once?

**UPDATE**

I realise now that what I effectively need is a recursive way to iterate over HTML elements with the ability to change them as I iterate over them.

Comment: So the non-English text will all be unicode?

Comment: *"`<span class="englishText">It is me, 你好</span>`"* – yeah, if that's supposed to be "English" too, this is a very vague problem statement. In general though, you'll probably simply want to iterate through *all* text nodes, regex out the ASCII characters and replace the text node with a new set of nodes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should travel through `siblings` that way you won't get in trouble with such a cases...

Something like that:

```
<?php

foreach ($html->find('div') as $element)
{
   foreach($element->next_sibling() as $sibling){
      echo $sibling->plaintext()."\n";
   }
}

?>
```

Or much easier way imo:

Just...

1. Change every `<*>` to `"\n"."<*>"` with `preg_replace()`;
2. Make an array of lines  like `$lines = explode("\n",$html_string);`

3.

```
   foreach($lines as $line){
      $text = strip_tags($line);
      echo $text;    
   }
```