# How to check if character is a english?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find some text only if it contains english words using Quicksand font. So when the user change to chinese, the text will change using Kaiti font. When the user reverts back to english, the text will change using Quicksand. I am wondering what is the most efficient way to do this using Javascript/Jquery?

This is my css:

```
/* Kaiti Navigation Menu */
span.media-body:lang(zh){
   font-family:  KaiTi, san-serif!important;
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaaVS.png)

Comment: What is wrong with the css you have now?

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981619/how-to-change-different-language-to-different-font-size-at-same-line-without-uni/21982034

Comment: Do you want the user to change the language or do you want to automatically identify the language?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej nope. I want the chinese character to be kaiti. For english word, I want to use Quicksand when user change their preference language (in this case, its Chinese)

Comment: does your span have a lang attribute?